# generic markov chain in r

Tags: r, igraph, markov-chains

I need construct a generic markov chain from the following data for the weather patterns in newyork. There are three regions- manhattan, bronx and queens- I need to have a overall markov chain graph that describes the average transition probabilities for the whole region.

```
state<- c('rainy', 'sunny', 'rainy', 'sunny', 'cold' ,'rainy', 'cold')
region<- c('manhttan', 'manhattan', 'bronx', 'bronx', 'queens', 'queens', 'queens')
df<- data.frame(region, state)

 library(markovchain)
 mcFit <- markovchainFit(data=df$state)
 print(mcFit)
 plot(mcFit$estimate, edge.arrow.size=.89)
```

any ideas?

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. What is wrong with `mcFit`? And why `igraph`?

Comment: these three regions are independent of each other and hence the transition from manhattan to queens doesn't make sense as they are not happening one after another

Comment: So do you then want three matrices and to average them?

Comment: yep thats right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following gives a list of transition matrices by region:

```
M <- tapply(state, region, function(s) 
  markovchainFit(data = s)$estimate@transitionMatrix)
```

Hence, the average one then is

```
Reduce("+", M) / length(M)
```

In this case it doesn't really work though, because there is too little data to estimate a decent matrix for each region.

Comment: can it be plotted?

Comment: @user3570187, given enough data you could plot it, e.g., with `heatmap`. Since it's an average, however, it's not the same kind of object as your `mcFit`, so you cannot directly plot it as a directed graph. You may use, e.g., `igraph` with `g <- graph_from_adjacency_matrix(Reduce("+", M) / length(M), weighted = TRUE)`, and then plot this `g` in the way that you wish.

Comment: I plotted this but it it not giving the values, why so? plot(g)

Comment: I got the transition values by your answer, but i cannot see it in the visual

Comment: That's actually another question, since you didn't mention it in your original post.. But `plot(g, edge.label = round(E(g)$weight, 3))` should work.

Comment: Thanks! I am getting this error called Error in f(init, x[[i]]) : non-conformable arrays, any suggestions?

Comment: @user3570187, look at `M`; some of the matrices have different dimensions, just as in your example with too little data. That is, the estimated chains are not using the same set of states. If you cannot get more data (where each state would be present in each region), then you could add some zero rows and columns to equalize the dimensions.